# Using Installshield with TeamCity and MSBuild

Tags: forms, installation, teamcity, installshield

I am using TeamCity to build and prepare a Windows Forms application. I've got a few projects in the solution, one of these being the .isproj which is an Installshield Project. I'm using the free developer version that Installshield so nicely provide for us.

However, TeamCity obviously can't build this, because the box doesn't have Installshield installed.

I can't install the same version because it requires Visual Studio, which is a bit of a pain.

Does anyone know if there is a free version that we could use on our Build Server to generate the artefacts for release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if InstallShield LE is available in the VS Express edition, which you could install on your build machine.

Another alternative would be to use another tool, for example [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) also has integration with VS and full command line support, so you can integrate it in your build machine. Also, you can install it separately on the build machine, without any edition of VS. It has the "Simple" project in the free edition, any other project types require a commercial license.

Comment: Hi Bogdan - thanks for the tips. I think that installing VS on the build box might be the solution - we don't have too many projects with installers, so there's not too much of a dependency within the organisation on a particular tool, so Advanced Installer is something I will take a look at. Again - thanks for taking the time!